# .innerHTML returns undefined on <p> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, innerhtml

I have a class that creates a typewriter effect on an `<p>` element that contains some text. See the HTML and JavaScript below.

I have a class in JavaScript that handles the animation part. This must be a class since there will be other things happening.

```js
var ani;
$(document).ready(function() {
  ani = new Animate_text("test sentence", false, 30);
  ani.writer();
});



class Animate_text {

  constructor(text, dynamic, speed) {
    this.text = text;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.dynamic = dynamic;
    this.chars = text.length;
    this.text_loc = 0;
    this.timerID = null;
    this.animate_image = false;
  }



  writer() {
    var sContents = "";
    var destination = document.getElementById("text");
    console.log(destination.innerHTML);
    destination.innerHTML = this.sContents + this.text.substring(0, this.text_loc) + "";

    if (this.text_loc++ == this.chars) {
      this.text_loc = 0;
      if (this.dynamic) {
        window.clearTimeout(this.timerID);
        ani = null;
      } else {
        window.clearTimeout(this.timerID);
        ani = null;
      }
    } else {
      this.timerID = setTimeout(function() {
        if (ani != null) {
          ani.writer();
        }
      }, this.speed)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slide_main_container">
  <div id="text_container">
    <div id="two_dots_container">
      <img src="supporting_data/dots.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="text_wrapper">
      <p id="text"></p> //
      <-- this is the element i want to target. </div>
    </div>
    <div id="image_container">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so when i animate the text i get `"undefined" + text` why is this happening? see image below for demonstration of the problem: 
[image]

so it should just say `"spanish not dynamic text"` instead of `"undefinedspanish not dynamic text"`

So to recap I don't understand why the undefined gets added? And how can I remove this undefined. I tried `substring()` but this didn't affect the undefined only the good sentence.

I am not sure myself why this is happening. If you need more context or if the question is not clear let me know.

Comment: `destination.innerHTML = this.sContents +`  sContents is a local var, so it's ``destination.innerHTML = sContents +``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove "`this`" on "`this.sContents`"

```js
var ani;
$(document).ready(function(){
 ani = new Animate_text("test sentence", false, 30);
 ani.writer();
});



class Animate_text{
 
 constructor(text, dynamic, speed){
  this.text = text;
  this.speed = speed;
  this.dynamic = dynamic;
  this.chars = text.length;
  this.text_loc = 0;
  this.timerID = null;
  this.animate_image = false;
 }

 writer(){
 var sContents = "";
 var destination = document.getElementById("text");
 destination.innerHTML = sContents + this.text.substring(0, this.text_loc) + "";
 
 if ( this.text_loc++ == this.chars ) {
  this.text_loc = 0;
  if (this.dynamic) {
   window.clearTimeout(this.timerID);
   // animation.setup();
   // animation.draw_points();
   ani = null;
  }else{
   window.clearTimeout(this.timerID);
   this.animate_image = true;
   //here we call the animate class
   // animate_image.draw_text();
   ani = null;
  }
 }else{
  this.timerID = setTimeout(function(){
   if(ani != null){
    ani.writer();
   }
  }, this.speed)
 }
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div id="slide_main_container">
  <div id="text_container">
   <div id="two_dots_container">
    <img src="supporting_data/dots.jpg">
   </div>
   <div id="text_wrapper">
    <p id="text"></p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="image_container">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks this works! will accept as answer in 9 min :)

Answer (score 2):

`this.sContents` is `undefined`. You indeed never declare a property on the class under that name. There is however a variable called `sContents`. I suspect you intend to insert the following line instead:

```
destination.innerHTML =
      sContents
    + this.text.substring(0, this.text_loc)
    + "";
```